# Magento API V2 SOAP - Obter apenas produtos vendidos

Tags: magento

Existe algum método da API que me retorne apenas os produtos que foram vendidos, ou tiveram alteração no atributo price/stock?

Comment: Mais vendidos ou todos os vendidos?

Comment: No caso os vendidos, pois eu sei que estes tiveram o estoque(stok) alterado.